# One controller's actions not appearing in help docs

Tags: asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.5

I have an MVC Web API project which is all working fine, but for some reason the entries in the help docs for just one of the controllers does not appear.

This was all fine until just recently, unfortunately though I don't know at what point it disappeared but it definitely used to be there.

The XML comments all look ok.
The XmlDocument.xml file looks correct.

Is there a way to specify which controllers and methods feature in the help docs?
How can I make sure the actions for this controller appear?

In case it helps, this is a snip with the first action:

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get details of a user or all users, including accounts and group memberships
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="username">The name of the user, if a single result is required</param>
    /// <param name="account">The account id, if multiple results are required</param>
    /// <param name="offset">The first row to return</param>
    /// <param name="limit">The maximum number of rows to return</param>
    /// <param name="sortby">The column to sort by, if required</param>
    /// <param name="order">The sort order; asc[ending] (default) or desc[ending]</param>
    /// <returns>Response structure including status and error message (if appropriate), as well as User structure including account and group details</returns>
    [Route("user")]
    [CombinedAuthentication(AuthLevel = "2")]
    [HttpGet]
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public UserGetResponse Get(string username = "", int account = 0, int offset = 0, int limit = 0, string sortby = "", string order = "")
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
            return new UserGetResponse(username);
        }
        else
        {
            return new UserGetResponse(account, offset, limit, sortby, order);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bit stops the help docs entry being generated:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
```

I removed that and all was fine!